# TI Calculator Programming, Won't Display Graph?

Tags: ti-basic

So I'm making an achievement system in a game, and I'm having a little trouble. You click on achievements, then trophy case, and then inspect for a description of each achievement. I got this working earlier, but I don't know what I changed. Can you take a look at a chunk of the code?

```
:Lbl 15

:ClrDraw

:Text(5,8,[argument]

:

:

:Line(-10,6,10,-6)
```

Basically, it should pull up the graph, and make the line and text. Instead it displays the home screen, and when I press ENTER, it goes back to the beginning of the program. Is there something wrong here?

Comment: Also, the set of code continues for a while and has an END at the end. I've tried putting a DispGraph before after ClrDraw, but that didn't do anything.

Comment: I think you need to post a bit more code...

Comment: This doesn't make a trophy case, but it does draw a nice triangle: http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/sierpinski-triangle

Answer (score 0):

Try saving a blank image as a picture (for instance Pic1), then recall this using the "RecallPic" command. This will get you to the graphing screen. From there do all of your plotting commands like "Text" and "Line". If this doesn't work then I'd say you need to post some more code, cause there's some other problem than simply displaying. 
 Also, check to make sure all of your loops and "if/then" statements have an "end" on them. You mentioned there was an unknown "end" at the end... That can cause a lot of trouble. It's the equivalent of missing an end parentheses or bracket in other languages.

Answer (score 0):

The `DispGraph` command will display the graph screen. The code you have shown, however, is right, and should display the graph screen automatically.

I would advise that you look over your code, specifically the `Goto` statement leading to `Lbl 15`, and make sure it's pointing to the right place. If it is, then the problem is probably after the code you have shown. You mentioned that this block of code has an `End` at the end; why? `Lbl`s should not have a corresponding `End`, if it is there, it will jump back to the most recent loop control block, which could cause any number of problems.